# Emacs replace a comma within a quoted string using Replace Regexp

Tags: regex, emacs

I have a csv files that contains commas in quoted strings e.g

1,2,"34,123",4

I am trying to replace the commas within the quoted string using Replace Regexp
("[^",]+),([^"]+")
with
$1$2

however emacs returns 0 occurrences found. Any ideas?

Thanks
Bob

Comment: Thanks for the reply Drew. I'll have a read of the suggested documents. I haven't used the Emacs Lisp before. Do you mean that the code you posted is run once I selected the buffer containing my data using M-x eval-buffer?

Answer (score 1):

This is what you want:

```
(while (re-search-forward "\"[^\",]+\\(,\\)[^\"]+\"")
  (replace-match "" nil nil nil 1))
```

You really need to read the doc about `replace-regexp`, as well as the doc about regexps in Emacs Lisp.

Trying to use `replace-regexp` non-interactively to perform replacements that reference parts of the match is a no-no. You want to use a loop that repeatedly matches text and then calls `replace-match` to replace it or parts of it.

Start with studying how Elisp represents regexps. Then learn the special syntax that `replace-match` uses for referring to parts of the match - it's not `$1` etc.